# Extra mining fees added in etherbase account

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, geth-debugging, java

1st scenario -

I have set miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[1]) and gasPrize is 0.

1 coin Transaction -

And done transaction from 0th account to one random account. I expect 0 mining fees will add in 1st(Etherbase) account but it will get 3000000000000000000 mining fees in 1st(Etherbase) account.

in this scenario 0 mining cost deducted from sender account.

2nd scenario -

I have set miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[1]) and gasPrize is 100.

1 coin Transaction -

And done transaction from 0th account to one random account. I expect 2508000 mining fees will add in 1st(Etherbase) account but it will get 9000000000002508000 mining fees in 1st(Etherbase) account.

in this scenario 2508000 mining cost deducted from sender account.

I am not understanding that why extra mining cost added in 1st(Etherbase) account in both scenario.

Comment: What client are you using? Is the blockchain a PoW or a PoA? Can you show a detail of the block/transaction? It appears to be the block reward.